# How to remove the ADD USER in the “admin users area” in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I already did the admin only register but I would like to remove this tab if anyone can help me

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done using [template_process_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_page/7) by adding this code to the template.php of your admin theme:

```
global $user;
$thisPath = current_path();
if($user->uid != 1 && strpos($thisPath, 'admin/people') !== false && strpos($thisPath, 'admin/people/create'))
{
    if(in_array('admin/people/create', $variables['action_links'][0]['#link'])) unset($variables['action_links'][0]);
}
else if($user->uid != 1 && strpos($thisPath, 'admin/people/create') !== false)
{
    drupal_set_message("Sorry, You Don't Have Permission to Access That Page", 'warning');
    drupal_goto('admin/people');
}
```

- this first checks the url for admin/people and looks for the action link associated with the Add User page element - if it finds one, it removes it
- the second checks the url for admin/people/create and sets a warning message, then redirects to the main admin/people page - in case someone manually tries to enter the address. This part could instead be included in any number of other hooks, including hook_boot() if you want it to trigger earlier in the process
- in either case it is set up to restrict access to everyone but user 1. You can change this to include specific roles if you prefer using in_array() on $user->roles

If you use Seven as your admin theme, copy the theme folder to sites/all/themes and then reset it as your admin theme so you can make the necessary changes

Answer (score 1):

That link is available to users with the "Administer users" permission enabled. You can disable that permission for all roles other than a role you create, and then give your account that role (or users you want to delegate this to), which would result in only you (or a limited number of people) with access to that link.  Hope that helps!

Comment: that removes access to all users access including editing and deleting while OP seems to only want to remove Add New User functionality

Comment: That's where it gets tricky since out-of-the-box Drupal has a ton of functionality wrapped up into the single "Administer users" permission.

Some modules worth looking at:
http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole

Comment: Sorry, fat-fingered the enter key... what I meant to type:

That's where it gets tricky since out-of-the-box Drupal has a ton of functionality wrapped up into the single "Administer users" permission.

Some modules worth looking at:
http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole 
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Could help accomplish what you're trying to do, but I'm flying in the dark here.  There are also some clever Views+Rules+VBO things you can do to selectively create admin actions without providing unlimited administrative access.

Comment: yes, but that alone does not answer the question asked by OP, this seems very incomplete and useless to someone who doesn't know intimate information about core functionality

Comment: Sure, I see your point...  How would you answer this question?

Comment: I added an answer

Comment: As I said this is not the solution I'm looking for, I already did this and It doesn't work.